# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'RemoveClass'

Tags: javascript, jquery, removeclass

I am trying to place onClick actions on two buttons (Managed and Unmanaged) which determines the style of multiple elements that have the 'managed-only-trigger' class.

The clicking of the Unmanaged button works fine, but when clicking Managed, the removeClass function doesn't seem to be working (it should remove the 'cloud-text-managed-only' override class and return the div to a normal style), it's throwing the following error:

Here is the jQuery and an example element (for reference):

```
// Managed / Unmanaged Functions
$( "#tab-managed" ).click(function() {
    // re-enable the managed features
    $( ".managed-only-trigger" ).RemoveClass( "cloud-text-managed-only" );
});

$( "#tab-unmanaged" ).click(function() {
  // Ensure that we switch managed elements to disabled:
  $( ".managed-only-trigger" ).addClass( "cloud-text-managed-only" );

});

<li class="cloud-tick managed-only-trigger">Some text that when unmanaged is clicked will turn grey based on the stylesheet</li>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The method is called `removeClass`. JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its 'removeClass' Not 'RemoveClass' :

```
 $( ".managed-only-trigger" ).removeClass( "cloud-text-managed-only" );
```